# addArgumentResolver not being invoked in config class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a config class with `@EnableMVC` and `Configuration` annotations. I have extended the `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` class and overridden the `addArgumentResolver` method to add one. However that method is never getting called. I have done a system output to test whether it gets invoked or not. Strangely, I tried overriding the `addInterceptor` method to the same class and it gets invoked just fine. Any clue to what is happening here would be apprecitated.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.fico.cardinal")
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebContextConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Bean
public ValidateJson validateJson() {
    System.out.println("Created bean validate json");
    return new ValidateJson();
}

@Bean
private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter() {
    return new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
} 

@Bean
public ValidateJsonSchema validateJsonSchema() {
    System.out.println("Created bean validate json schema");
    return new ValidateJsonSchema();
}

@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(
        List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
    argumentResolvers.add(validateJsonSchema());
    System.out.println("Added resolver");
    // doesn't gets called
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    super.addInterceptors(registry);
    registry.addInterceptor(validateJson());
    System.out.println("added interceptor");
    // gets called
}
```

Edit: Included the complete config class

Comment: Extend from WebMvcConfigurationSupport :)

Comment: No, it does not work. It did not even create the Interceptor this time.

Comment: Remove the bean for `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` that is already registered by `@EnableWebMvc`. Don't call the super methods, those are just empty.

Comment: Thank you, but I had already figured that out after a day of hair-pulling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I had not posted all the information in the beginning, which might have deterred someone from solving this issue. But after some research of my own, I found out the error.

When you check the call hierarchy of `addArgumentResolver`, you will find that it gets called by `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` which is a declared as a bean in the Spring classes. Now, if you look at my config class, I have declared my own bean of `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` class which overwrites the default bean. Hence `addArgumentResolver` was never called.

So the solution is to remove the bean `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` from your config class.

Answer (score 1):

In my case changing

```
extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport
```

to

```
implements WebMvcConfigurer
```

worked